# Android OnTouchEvent not fire at first touch

Tags: android

OnTouchEvent is being fired after the second time touch; yet, I want it to be fired after the first touch itself.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    //too avoid touch being detected continuously
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            if (Function.system[5] == "Gravity: on") {

            //some action...
            }
    }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

Comment: what is your return?

Comment: The issue is with the focus, try to get the focus to view before touch event then see if the same issue still persist.

Comment: I really don't know how to focus to it. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Android to continue to respond to touch events. Returning true let's you capture events from action down , action move and then action up.

Comment: I forget to add it; I use return super.onTouchEvent(event) to return.

Comment: but the issue still remains

Answer (score 0):

Please add the return true for each event

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        //too avoid touch being detected continuously
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {


        }

        return true;
}
```

Please try and seee if this works for you

Comment: @myworldbox on returning true also?

Comment: It doesn't work at first click, which it works at second click onward.

Comment: may be it is issue with focus.

Comment: I think it is not, as I use the same Java class to implement two games: X in a row and apple chess; the onTouchEvent only fails at apple chess but not XInARow. I think may be it is a issue with Function.system[5] but I don't know how to solve it.